# Linking/Mapping columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of two columns of `title` and `text`.

The data frame looks like this:

| title | text |
| --- | --- |
| foreign keys | A foreign key is a column or group of columns... |
| **Week 2** | In Week 2 the encoding... |
| comments | *colection of comments about **Week 2*** |
| **Statistics** | Statistics is the discipline... |
| comments | *collection of comments about **Statistics*** |

The data frame basically says the comments of a topic are **exactly** present below it. So I want to **link/map** these two things such that if I give the name of the topic (`title`) it will retrieve its corresponding review (`text`). In this example since Topic 1 does not have any reviews, I don't need them. By this, I want to reduce the size of my data frame to an extent by keeping only reviews related topics.

So far I could do only the following:

```
df %>% 
  filter(title == "Week 2") %>% 
  pull(text)
```

which gives me the `text` corresponding to it (which is obvious) and not the review of *comments about Week 2*. And for Topics that do not have any reviews below it, I do not need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to `filter` the 'Topic' having the 'review' by creating a grouping column.  Once we subset the data, it is easier to `pull` the 'text' or create a named vector of 'text' with `title`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(title, '^Topic'))) %>% 
 filter(any(str_detect(title, 'review')) & str_detect(text, 'text'))  %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  title   text              grp
  <chr>   <chr>           <int>
1 Topic 2 text of Topic 2     2
2 Topic 3 text of Topic 3     3
```

---

For the updated data

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(str_detect(title, 'comments')) != 1))) %>%  
  filter(any(str_detect(title, 'comments') ) & title != 'comments') %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  title      text                              grp
  <chr>      <chr>                           <int>
1 Week 2     In Week 2 the encoding...           2
2 Statistics Statistics is the discipline...     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(title = c("Topic 1", "Topic 2", "review 2", "Topic 3", 
"review 3"), text = c("text of Topic 1", "text of Topic 2", "review of Topic 2", 
"text of Topic 3", "review of Topic 3")), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(title = c("foreign keys", "Week 2", "comments", 
"Statistics", "comments"), text = c("A foreign key is a column or group of columns...", 
"In Week 2 the encoding...", "colection of comments about Week 2", 
"Statistics is the discipline...", "collection of comments about Statistics"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks, @arun, I got the idea behind the grouping. However, I have arbitrary text like updated in the question.

Comment: Yes, `comments` are common in the data frame. And the text beside it has all the comments related to the topic above it.